# how to reinstall ubuntu on its own disk?

Tags: dual-boot

I currently have dual boot on one SSD disk (on two separate partitions, windows 10 + ubuntu 16).

I am planning to buy a second SSD and re-install ubuntu on the new SSD. What is the recommended sequence for me to do this?

After I re-install ubuntu on the new hard drive, I do want to remove the existing ubuntu partition and reclaim the space for windows 10

Note:

I don't need to move the linux installation to another drive. I don't have data on the linux installation. I only want to reinstall linux from scratch (and delete the original linux installation)

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: @karel I don't need to move the linux installation to another drive. I don't have data on the linux installation. I now just want to reinstall.

Comment: If you only want to install Ubuntu on a new drive, it seems no different from installing Ubuntu in the usual way. Choose the correct device when running the installer and that's it?

Answer (score 0):

As you are planning to buy a second SSD, you might consider this scenario:
Make sure the new SSD is larger or exactly the same size as the current.
Boot the Ubuntu Live USB, open a terminal and use `dd` to copy the whole old disk to the new.
Boot the system and use boot sequence to boot from the new disk.
As this is the disk you want to use for Ubuntu, you can use `gparted` to remove the Windows partition, update Grub and you are done.

Restart the system again, select the old disk to boot into Windows, remove the Ubuntu partition and expand the Windows partition.

That leaves you with the dual boot configs on both disks. The easiest would be to set the default OS per disk and TimeOut to 0.